# binding navigator to next item in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bindingnavigator

I am still new to visual basic 2010. 
I would like to change the option of binding navigator because it always move to the next row.
How could I make it to move to the next 9 rows? 
For example is this:
I load form main and fill 9 rows of data by adding code:

```
Dim inc As Integer =  0 
label1.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(inc + 0).Items(2) 
label2.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(inc + 1).Items(2) 
.....
label9.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(inc + 8).Items(2)
```

but when I debug and press next item, all the value of  `label1.Text ---> label9.Text` 
 are filled with rows number two.... Could you help me guys?

Answer (score 0):

There is alot wrong that I see you have going on here... Check out my edits...

```
 Dim inc As Integer = 0 'This isn't doing anything...

 label1.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(inc + 0).Items(2) 'Your always referencing item 2
 label2.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(inc + 1).Items(2)

 label9.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(inc + 8).Items(2)
```

First change all of your labels text to this...

```
 label1.Text = dataSet.Tables("DPT").Rows(1).Item(1) 'Change the number for your row and item as you go down... Or better yet use your Item name instead of the number...
```

Comment: Uhm I can see that. but that doesn't make any changes when I wanna to press next item. It will show up the next row, that is row number two. I want it show row number 9 to 18, each time I press the button next. DO you know it?